# Dynamics 365 CRM: Sudden JS Error

Tags: json, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Using Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (8.2.2.112) on-premises. On the Quote form, I have modified the action called by the Activate Quote to create a custom entity (Deal) record and then navigate to the newly created record. This worked perfectly fine in all browsers until 2 weeks ago. Now, it doesn't work in IE (client preferred - but does work in Chrome, Firefox and Edge) and all I get is some generic JSON error. "Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content."

No amount of debugging that I add seems to add any clarity.  I am getting a 400 error in IE on the XMLHttpRequest at
https://xxx.xxx.com/CRM/api/data/v8.2/quotes(04224AF9-DD70-E811-8123-000D3A02DFDB)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.new_SubmitQuote

- The full Response Body is pasted below.
- The full JSON is pasted below

This is the JS that calls the action (new_SubmitQuote) to create the new Deal entity record and then navigate to that new record.

```
n.xxx_submitQuote=function(n){
    r.showXrmProgressIndicator("Submitting, please wait...");
     u.executeBoundAction("quotes",n,"new_SubmitQuote").then(function(n){
        t.Utility.openEntityForm("sut_deal",n.sut_dealid,null,null)}).catch(r.logError).then(function(){
            r.closeXrmProgressIndicator()
        })
    }
```

Any thoughts, ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am stumped.

Thanks,
Noah

**JSON**

```js
{  
   "@odata.context":"https://xxx.xxx.com/CRM/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#quotes/$entity",
   "@odata.etag":"W/\"54328330\"",
   "new_spread":95903.0200,
   "new_amount10percent":310777.7900,
   "new_revenue10":777.79,
   "new_paymentcount_date":"2018-06-19T00:53:29Z",
   "_pricelevelid_value":"bfa9dc95-dbcd-e611-80d7-000d3a01f3fc",
   "exchangerate":1.0000000000,
   "totaldiscountamount":0.0000,
   "name":"100026",
   "totallineitemamount":0.0000,
   "_transactioncurrencyid_value":"9107a2c3-bab1-e611-80d2-000d3a01f3fc",
   "_owninguser_value":"a9c113ac-d532-e811-8119-000d3a02dfdb",
   "totalamount":0.0000,
   "_ownerid_value":"a9c113ac-d532-e811-8119-000d3a02dfdb",
   "versionnumber":54328330,
   "quoteid":"04224af9-dd70-e811-8123-000d3a02dfdb",
   "totallineitemdiscountamount":0.0000,
   "timezoneruleversionnumber":0,
   "totalamountlessfreight_base":0.0000,
   "statuscode":1,
   "createdon":"2018-06-15T20:52:12Z",
   "totaltax_base":0.0000,
   "totallineitemamount_base":0.0000,
   "totalamount_base":0.0000,
   "modifiedon":"2018-06-15T20:53:23Z",
   "totaltax":0.0000,
   "totaldiscountamount_base":0.0000,
   "quotenumber":"QUO-38015-F3D2B8",
   "_modifiedby_value":"a9c113ac-d532-e811-8119-000d3a02dfdb",
   "revisionnumber":0,
   "_createdby_value":"a9c113ac-d532-e811-8119-000d3a02dfdb",
   "pricingerrorcode":0,
   "totallineitemdiscountamount_base":0.0000,
   "statecode":0,
   "_owningbusinessunit_value":"1a1ad33f-bab1-e611-80d2-000d3a01f3fc",
   "willcall":false,
   "_customerid_value":"7a60bf77-dd70-e811-8123-000d3a02dfdb",
   "billto_addressid":null,
   "discountpercentage":null,
   "shipto_composite":null,
   "onholdtime":null,
   "billto_line2":null,
   "closedon":null,
   "paymenttermscode":null,
   "freightamount_base":null,
   "_modifiedonbehalfby_value":null,
   "freightamount":null,
   "billto_city":null,
   "_campaignid_value":null,
   "shipto_line1":null,
   "_contactid_value":null,
   "requestdeliveryby":null,
   "freighttermscode":null,
   "billto_stateorprovince":null,
   "effectivefrom":null,
   "shipto_line3":null,
   "discountamount_base":null,
   "billto_line3":null,
   "shipto_telephone":null,
   "shipto_contactname":null,
   "expireson":null,
   "shipto_freighttermscode":null,
   "shipto_line2":null,
   "shipto_addressid":null,
   "_opportunityid_value":null,
   "shipto_fax":null,
   "shipto_country":null,
   "shipto_stateorprovince":null,
   "billto_composite":null,
   "billto_line1":null,
   "billto_contactname":null,
   "billto_telephone":null,
   "shipto_city":null,
   "_owningteam_value":null,
   "discountamount":null,
   "description":null,
   "shippingmethodcode":null,
   "processid":null,
   "_accountid_value":null,
   "_slainvokedid_value":null,
   "stageid":null,
   "traversedpath":null,
   "billto_postalcode":null,
   "utcconversiontimezonecode":null,
   "shipto_name":null,
   "overriddencreatedon":null,
   "billto_fax":null,
   "effectiveto":null,
   "importsequencenumber":null,
   "_new_createdby_value":null,
   "shipto_postalcode":null,
   "lastonholdtime":null,
   "billto_name":null,
   "_slaid_value":null,
   "_createdonbehalfby_value":null,
   "billto_country":null,
}
```

**ERROR**

```js
    {
    "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.",
    "innererror":{
    "message":"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.","type":"Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException","stacktrace":"
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataUtilities.ValidateInputParameters(ModelStateDictionary controllerModelState)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.PostBoundAction(String entityName, String key, String operationName, ODataUntypedActionParameters parameters)
    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult. <ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are using JS promises which may not be supported by some versions of IE referring [mozilla.org](https://developer.c/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/prototype) [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises), however you may workaround it by trying regular action call with callback parameters for opening the entity form, check sample below, consider changing API version.

```
function ExecuteAction(entitySet, entityId, actionName, Parameters, successCallBack, ErrorCallBack, isAsync) {
debugger;
var clientUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var isAsync = isAsync || false;
var result = {};
entityId = entityId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", clientUrl + "/api/data/v8.1/" + entitySet + "(" + entityId + ")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM." + actionName, isAsync);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        var s = this.status;
        if (s >= 200 && s < 300) { //success 
            result.status = true;
            result.data = this.response;
            if (successCallBack) 
                successCallBack();

        } else if (s >= 400 && s < 500) { // client error 
            result.status = false;
            console.log("Client error");
            result.error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
            console.log(result.error);
            console.log(result.error.message);
            if (ErrorCallBack)
                ErrorCallBack(result);


        } else if (s >= 500) { //server error 
            result.status = false;
            console.log("Server error");
            result.error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
            console.log(result.error);
            console.log(result.error.message);
            if (ErrorCallBack) 
                ErrorCallBack(result);

        }

if (Parameters == "" || Parameters == null) {
    req.send();
} else {
    req.send(JSON.stringify(Parameters));
}

return result;
```

}